# SQL get fields in a column where a word appears only once

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, where-clause

So say I have this table:

```
  -- column --
  word1
  word2
  word3 word4
  word
```

How do I get only the fields from this colum where 'word' appears only once? Like this:

```
  -- colum --
  word1
  word2
  word
```

I am using PostgreSQL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses string functions like so:

```
select *
from mytable
where char_length(col) - char_length(replace(col, 'word', '')) = char_length('word')
```

The idea is to replace all occurrences of "word" in the string, and take the difference of the resulting string with the original. If the difference is 4, then we know there was only one match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `char_length` of the column and use it as follows:

```
select * from your_table
where char_length(replace(col, 'word', '')) 
       = char_length(col) - char_length('word')
```

Comment: Thank you! You and the guy above gave the same great answer. Too bad I can't accept both of them as a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the question as your wanting values that only consist of one word.  This is another way of saying that there is no space:

```
select *
from t
where col not like '% %';
```

If you *happen* to have empty strings (but not `NULL` values) on rows and you don't want those, you can ensure that there is a value using:

```
select *
from t
where col not like '% %' and col like '%_%'
```

That does not seem necessary based on your sample data.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I needed. I marked the answer is was looking for as the solution, but thanks anyways! :D